# About ComboBox SelectedIndex?

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

I have a combobox and list of it was from separate strings declared on a class .

```
sample:
as
asd
asdf
asdfg
asdfg
```

Everytime when i run it, it always selects the last part of list of combobox instead of firstpart. It is selecting `asdfg` instead of `as`.My question is how to make the list to be selected from first, that is starting from `as` as the selected index for the combobox? (or always in accending mode when alphabetically arranged)? thanks in advance..

Comment: note that the list are in string mode and not data .ty again

Comment: descending??? or reverse

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try by [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.sort.aspx) and [reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.collections.arraylist.reverse.aspx) :

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   ArrayList list = ArrayList.Adapter(comboBox1.Items);
   list.Sort();
   // if you want to reverse
   list.Reverse();
   comboBox1.SelectedItem=0;
 }
```

Comment: From what I understand, the OP wants to select the first item by default and not sort existing items.

Comment: the arraylist doesnt exist

Comment: i put this: using System.Collections; and i worked .problem was it just reverse but selected item was still the last :( ...

Comment: i thought if it was reverse then selected item will change also but i was wrong ...

Comment: it worked when i changed it to lb.SelectedItem = 1; bigthanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 after adding elements to the ComboBox.

Thus you get:

```
comboBox.Items.Add("as");
comboBox.Items.Add("asd");
comboBox.Items.Add("asdf");
comboBox.Items.Add("asdfg");
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Comment: Can you edit your original question to reflect the complete current code?